# How to model and predict a user's preference by their click-through history?

Tags: modeling, recommender-system

I am trying to model my users' food preferences so that I can recommend restaurants which he/she might be satisfied. The following is some sample data:

```
uid    categories                                         action   count  
-----  -------------------------------------------------  -------  -----  
user1  American                                           display  5      
user1  American                                           open     2        
user1  Irish                                              display  5      
user1  Irish                                              open     1      
user1  Italian                                            display  6      
user1  Local Flavor                                       display  6                  
user1  Seafood                                            display  6            
user2  Barbeque                                           display  6          
user2  Barbeque                                           open     1      
user2  Coffee & Tea                                       display  2          
user2  Local Flavor                                       display  6            
user2  Pizza,Italian                                      display  2      
user2  Sandwiches,Salad,Soup                              display  4      
user2  Sandwiches,Salad,Soup                              open     2      
user2  Seafood                                            display  1      
user2  Sushi Bars,Japanese                                display  2
```

As you can see, we can calculate the click through rate (CTR) by the counts of action 'display' and 'open', and I want to maximize the CTR for the recommendations.

Since this is a secondary function on a mobile app, the conventional recommendation techniques like SVD or ALS which needs heavy computation might not be appropriate. Is there any other approach so that I can model and predict the users' preference?

Comment: Do you use only the categories of restaurants, or is there some data collected about the individual restautants?

Comment: @sandris No, the data is queried from Yelp Search API, so only few fields are available.